# Google App Script Export CSV onEdit, not onOpen

Tags: javascript, csv, google-apps-script

I've created a form that populates all field data into a google form and I have a script that will export the spreadsheet to a csv every time the spreadsheet is edited. But, the script only runs when the sheet is open and is edited on the sheet. If I submit my form that edits the spread sheet, the trigger doesn't fire and the csv is not created.

Under my current project triggers I have my event to run onedit.

How can I make my triggers fire when the sheet is not open?

```
function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Download Data",
    functionName : "saveAsCSV"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};

function saveAsCSV() {
   // Trash the previous csv file that was last updated.
 var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('myCSVFile.csv');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   if (file.getLastUpdated()) {
     file.setTrashed(true);
   }
 }
  // Creates the file name
  var fileName = ("myCSVFile");
  // Check that the file name entered wasn't empty
  if (fileName.length !== 0) {
    // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
    fileName = fileName + ".csv";
    // Convert the range data to CSV format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // Create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the CSV data
    DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a CSV file name.");
  }
}

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
  try {
    var csvFile = undefined;

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var data = rows.getValues();

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Try to write the function for `onFormSubmit()` trigger

Comment: Will this work even if this is an external form? Not a google form?

Comment: I'll try changing `var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();` for openById

Comment: @Harold I wouldn't need it to be open. I need the sheet to update automatically and the trigger to fire when the sheet is not open.

Comment: @iJay I wrote the function for form submit and did not see any results to fire the trigger.

Comment: @cgrouge you are not really opening it. It's the script that is opening it (as the trigger don't say to the function it launch the environment from where it need to be launched if you don't specify the spreadsheet with it's id, the `getActiveSpreadsheet`is not working (because it's nowhere).  `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` <===> `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()`

Comment: @Harold so it should look like this: 
function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Download Data",
    functionName : "saveAsCSV"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};

Comment: @Harold using the script i pasted above did not work

Comment: @cgrouge of course it didnt worked you used exactly the same code than in your post :D change `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()` for `SpreadsheetApp.openById(id)` where `id` is the id of your spreadsheet (it need quote around it)

Comment: @Harold not sure why I copied that bit. I meant to copy this: function onEdit(event) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1JW1B...A9kOk");
  var entries = [{
    name : "Download Data",
    functionName : "saveAsCSV"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
In my script editor the full id is in there

Comment: @Harold I'll also note that it still does not work with the openById. My triggers are not firing

Comment: if the triggers are not firing it's an other trouble in my opinion it's because you didn't use a programmable trigger, have a look at the doc here https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: My triggers will fire if the sheet is open and I make edits to the sheet. But if my sheet is closed and I submit my form that automatically updates the sheet, my saveAsCSV function doesn't fire until I open the sheet and make edits. I will look into installable triggers

Comment: @Harold thank you for your help! I took your suggestion and then edited my trigger. I posted the answer to this thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After getting help from comments above and adjust my triggers I have a solution.

Here is the script:

```
function onEdit() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  var entries = [{
    name : "Download Data",
    functionName : "saveAsCSV"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};

function saveAsCSV() {
   // Trash the previous csv file that was last updated.
 var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName('myCSVFile.csv');
 while (files.hasNext()) {
   var file = files.next();
   if (file.getLastUpdated()) {
     file.setTrashed(true);
   }
 }
  // Creates the file name
  var fileName = ("myCSVFile");
  // Check that the file name entered wasn't empty
  if (fileName.length !== 0) {
    // Add the ".csv" extension to the file name
    fileName = fileName + ".csv";
    // Convert the range data to CSV format
    var csvFile = convertRangeToCsvFile_(fileName);
    // Create a file in the Docs List with the given name and the CSV data
    DriveApp.createFile(fileName, csvFile);
  }
  else {
    Browser.msgBox("Error: Please enter a CSV file name.");
  }
}

function convertRangeToCsvFile_(csvFileName) {
  try {
    var csvFile = undefined;

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
    var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
    var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
    var data = rows.getValues();

    // Loop through the data in the range and build a string with the CSV data
    if (data.length > 1) {
      var csv = "";
      for (var row = 0; row < data.length; row++) {
        for (var col = 0; col < data[row].length; col++) {
          if (data[row][col].toString().indexOf(",") != -1) {
            data[row][col] = "\"" + data[row][col] + "\"";
          }
        }

        // Join each row's columns
        // Add a carriage return to end of each row, except for the last one
        if (row < data.length-1) {
          csv += data[row].join(",") + "\r\n";
        }
        else {
          csv += data[row];
        }
      }
      csvFile = csv;
    }
    return csvFile;
  }
  catch(err) {
    Logger.log(err);
    Browser.msgBox(err);
  }
}
```

After saving the script file I needed to change my trigger from onEdit to a timed trigger. Resources > all your triggers I deleted the current saveAsCSV function and created a new one. Then selected time-driven, minutes timer, every minute.

Now when the sheet is closed, the function will run and create a new CSV file every minute.